# Making changes to a ntriples file with python

Tags: python, rdflib, n-triples

**Scenario:** I just got my hands on a huge ntriples file (6.5gb uncompressed). I am trying to open it and perform some operations (such as cleaning some of the data that it contains).

**Issue:** I haven't been able to check the contents of this file. Notepad++ cannot handle it, and in RDFlib, the far as I got was to load the file, but I cannot seem to find a way to edit without parsing the entire thing. I also tried using RDF package (from [how to parse big datasets using RDFLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678623/how-to-parse-big-datasets-using-rdflib)), but I cannot find a way to install it in Python 3.

**Question:** What is the best option to perform this kind of operation? Is there any command in rdflib that allows for this kind of editing?

Answer (score 0):

if it's ntriples then basically it's a line-by-line triples. Therefore, you can read the file by small chunks (some N lines from the file) and parse the chunk via rdflib followed by any cleaning operation you need on the graph.